# Raknet connection issue on Unity3D + iOS (il2cpp)

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, raknet

I have weird issue running the last version of Raknet on iOS with Unity3D: I get `CONNECTION_ATTEMPT_FAILED` when trying to connect to the server.

Now let's me detail the issue:

he exact same Library connects fine when used in an ObjectiveC application, so the issue seems to be Unity3D related.

I already managed to pinpoint my issue to be located in Raknet reliability layer:

Apparently, during the last step of the connection process (when the connection handshake as been completed) the reliability layer of the server thinks that the  `ID_CONNECTION_REQUEST` packet received from the client is an acknowledgment instead of a message. Therefore it doesn't answer. Ultimately after a few tries, (and a 10s timeout) the client fails with the `CONNECTION_ATTEMPT_FAILED` error.

Does anybody there as an idea? I will update the question when I manage to get more info.

#### Update

We are using Unity3D 5.1.1f1

We managed to find a workaround! See answer for more information. As the workaround doesn't tell us much about what really happened, I would gladly hear some C++/XCode/Unity/iOS/AppleLLVM6.1 experts around here explain what really happened.

Comment: I don't have a specific answer, but instead a question. What version of Unity are you using? Some earlier 5.0 and 5.1 versions had one or two Raknet bugs that have now been fixed.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Apparently I didn't received notifications. Apparently we are using Unity 5.1.1f1 . We managed find a workaround. Updating the question and adding an answer. The whole stuff remains weird however. If anyone has an explanation, I would gladly take it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the Raknet header wasn't properly generated by the iOS client. Namely we were sending ACK messages in place of `simple` packets. The rest of the message was considered as garbage by the server and the packet was dropped. The client kept trying to send the corrupted handshake packet a few times before timeouting.

This doesn't tell us why, doesn't it? Apparently the `serialize` method of the class `DatagramHeaderFormat` wasn't called as it should have been when running Raknet in Unity (iOS). Something else (and I don't know what) was linked in place of this method and was filling the `BitStream` with a corrupted header.

I am quite sure that the serialize method wasn't called because `printf` calls from inside weren't displayed in the console.

We renamed `DatagramHeaderFormat::serialize` into `DatagramHeaderFormat::serializeHeader`  and... voila, it works.

Now I only want to understand what did the compiler (and why).